# Accessing PrivateFontCollection Families by name

Tags: c#, fonts

I have a function to draw text using a custom font, and there's a few of them. I need to pass a string name to that function and make it draw using the Family that matches the name. And I don't want to blindly iterate through the collection and manually look for the given name. Is it possible, or iteration is really the only way?

```
    System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection CustomFonts = new System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection();
    // [...]
    void LoadCustomFont(Stream font)
    {
        byte[] fontdata = new byte[font.Length];
        font.Read(fontdata, 0, (int)font.Length);
        font.Close();
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* pFontData = fontdata)
            {
                CustomFonts.AddMemoryFont((System.IntPtr)pFontData, fontdata.Length);
            }
        }
    }
    using (var font0 = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("font0.ttf"))
            LoadCustomFont(font0);
    using (var font1 = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("font1.ttf"))
            LoadCustomFont(font1);
    // [...]
    // here, is Families[i] the only possible approach?
    var font = new Font(CustomFonts.Families[0], 8, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Comment: You have a very nasty bug in your code, the pointer you pass to AddMemoryFont() must remain stable as long as you use the font.  The *fixed* keyword is not good enough.  You must use Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem + Copy instead and not call FreeCoTaskMem until you can no longer use the font.  Expectation is that since you added the font to your resources, you should also know the family name.

Comment: why not just track the fonts you need to use by using a Dictionary or custom manager that you use to load fonts you're going to need once, and then just get fonts by name out of the dict/manager, afterwards?

Comment: @HansPassant can you elaborate on why the current approach with pointer is bad, and why the one you suggest is better?

Comment: You'll find out when you continue testing and using the font.  You'll see the font glyphs getting corrupted, sometimes an AccessViolationException.  No better explanation than seeing this go wrong by yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant I switched to this sample http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107376/Embedding-Font-To-Resources Does it look correct? I probably have to move FreeCoTaskMem to when my entire app closes?